# get sqlalchemy with apscheduler multithreading to work

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, apscheduler

I have a list of jobs I am adding to an [apscheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/) BlockingScheduler with a ThreadPoolExecutor number the same size as the number of jobs.

The jobs I am adding are using sqlalchemy and interacting with the same database, but i am getting errors:

`sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) database is locked`

I have used a scoped_session and a sessionmaker in my base sqlalchemy set-up.

```
    from os.path import join, realpath
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
    from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
    
    db_name = environ.get("DB_NAME")
    db_path = realpath(join( "data", db_name))
    engine = create_engine(f"sqlite:///{db_path}", pool_pre_ping=True)
    session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    Session = scoped_session(session_factory)
    Base = declarative_base()
```

Then an example of the scheduled job class I add to apscheduler I have something like this:

```
from app.data_structures.base import Base, Session, engine
from app.data_structures.job import Job

from app.data_structures.scheduled_job import ScheduledJob
from app.data_structures.user import User


class AccountingProcessorJob(ScheduledJob):
    name: str = "Accounting Processor"
    def __init__(self, resources: AppResources, depends: List[str] = None) -> None:
        super().__init__(resources)

    def job_function(self) -> None:
        account_dir = realpath(environ.get("ACCOUNTING_DIRECTORY"))
        Base.metadata.create_all(engine, Base.metadata.tables.values(), checkfirst=True)
        session = Session()
        try:
            #do some stuff with the session here e.g.
            # with some variables that are setup
            user = User(user_name=user_name)
            session.add(user)
            user.extend(jobs)
            session.commit()
        except:
            session.rollback()
        finally:
            Session.remove()
```

I was under the impression that using a scoped_session and a session factory would start a new session for each thread, and make it thread-safe.

where the User and Job are sqlalchemy orm objects, eg:

```
from sqlalchemy import Boolean, Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, mapped_column, relationship
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import false

from app.data_structures.base import Base
from app.data_structures.job import Job
    
    
    

class User(Base):
        __tablename__ = "users"
    
        user_name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(primary_key=True),
        employee_number = Column(Integer)
        manager = relationship("User", remote_side=[user_name], post_update=True)
        jobs: Mapped[list[Job]] = relationship()
    
        def __init__(
            self,
            user_name: str,
            employee_number: int = None,
            manager: str = None,
    
        ) -> None:
            self.user_name = user_name
            self.employee_number = employee_number
            self.manager = manager
```

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong, and how to go about fixing it?

Comment: Looks like you are using an older version of SQLAlchemy, what version are you using?

Comment: Also can you try to reduce this to a more repeatable concise example?  There is a lot of info missing.

Answer (score 1):

This example is using SQLAlchemy 1.4.48, apscheduler 3.10.1 and python module sqlite3 3.34.1.

I'm not sure how to fully recreate what is going on in your job function because it isn't clear where `jobs` or `.extend` in `user.extend(jobs)` comes from.

The create_all doesn't seem to work well in each job (throws errors that table already exists) so I put it in its own job and only ran it once ahead of the jobs that create users.

I used a random sleep to make sure the jobs would run intermittently and not in exact blocks of the max thread count.

```py
from os import environ
from time import sleep
from os.path import join, realpath
from secrets import randbelow

from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.schema import Column
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
from apscheduler.executors.pool import ThreadPoolExecutor

db_name = environ.get("DB_NAME")
db_path = realpath(join("data", db_name))
engine = create_engine(f"sqlite:///{db_path}", pool_pre_ping=True)
session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
Session = scoped_session(session_factory)
Base = declarative_base()


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String)


def setup_func():
    print("Running create_all")
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine, Base.metadata.tables.values(), checkfirst=True)


def job_function(i):
    print("Running job function {}".format(i))
    session = Session()
    try:
        seconds_to_wait = 1 + randbelow(4)
        sleep(seconds_to_wait)
        user = User(username=str(i))
        session.add(user)
        session.commit()
    finally:
        # Will rollback if needed.
        Session.remove()


FIFTEEN_MINUTES_IN_SECONDS = 15 * 60


def main():
    sched = BlockingScheduler(
        timezone="US/Pacific",
        executors={"default": ThreadPoolExecutor(4)},
        job_defaults={"misfire_grace_time": FIFTEEN_MINUTES_IN_SECONDS},
    )
    sched.add_job(setup_func)
    for i in range(100):
        sched.add_job(job_function, args=[i])
    sched.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```
$ rm -f data/test.sql && DB_NAME=test.sql ve/bin/python test_apscheduler.py 
/home/ian/workspace/laspilitas-project/stackoverflow-and-testing/test_apscheduler.py:18: MovedIn20Warning: Deprecated API features detected! These feature(s) are not compatible with SQLAlchemy 2.0. To prevent incompatible upgrades prior to updating applications, ensure requirements files are pinned to "sqlalchemy<2.0". Set environment variable SQLALCHEMY_WARN_20=1 to show all deprecation warnings.  Set environment variable SQLALCHEMY_SILENCE_UBER_WARNING=1 to silence this message. (Background on SQLAlchemy 2.0 at: https://sqlalche.me/e/b8d9)
  Base = declarative_base()
Running create_all
Running job function 0
Running job function 1
Running job function 2
Running job function 3
Running job function 4
Running job function 5
Running job function 6
Running job function 7
Running job function 8
Running job function 9
Running job function 10
Running job function 11
Running job function 12
Running job function 13
Running job function 14
Running job function 15
Running job function 16
Running job function 17
Running job function 18
Running job function 19
```

Comment: Based on my attempt maybe trying moving `create_all` into a single standalone job.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply - it seems the only thing you do differently is change the misfire_grace_time on the scheduler, which shouldnt really affect the sqlalchemy stuff? I guess you didnt have `check_first=True` in your create all initially. I have got to the bottom of my issue - I was leaving a session open for a long time. Refactoring where the session gets opened and putting  `connect_args={"timeout": 30}` in my create_engine call seems to have solved the problem.